# How to set the font family dynamically to text block inside listbox in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding, windows-phone-8, listbox, font-family

I'm developing one windows phone 8 application. This application has to work in two languages English and Arabic. For Each language I'm using some external font families.

In some pages I have listbox with text block. By default the application will open in English language. So I've mentioned the text block font family in the xaml itself.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="titleText" Text="{Binding serviceText}" Foreground="#FF3373AA"
Margin="5,5,5,5" FontWeight="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="28" 
FontFamily="Fonts/Hacen Tunisia Lt.ttf#Hacen Tunisia Lt" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
```

Now when the user changes the language from English to Arabic, Then I have to apply the font family (of arabic) to this text block.

**Could you please help me how to change the font family of the text block, which is in list box dynmically(based on the user selected language).**

I'm looking forward for your reply.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use converter and INotofyPropertyChanged

Comment: You have to bind the selected language property to font family of textblock.

Comment: Hi Xyroid, Could you please tell me how to bind the language to the font family of textblock. I'm new to windows phone 8 development.